# Send emails with wp_mail() using SMTP configured in plugin

Tags: plugins, wp-mail, smtp

I have the plugin Easy WP SMTP installed and there I have configured sending my WordPress mails with SMTP.

I send emails with a cronjob to my users with the `wp_mail()` function. I was asking myself, if the emails are sent with SMTP or do I need to add this functionality to `wp_mail()`?
If yes, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Easy WP SMTP should automatically handle mail sent with `wp_mail()`. After all, that's how all the other emails are sent. Whether there's anything special you need to do to support it is something you'll need to ask its developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using something like Easy WP SMTP, what you're doing is configuring things so that `wp_mail()` sends using your validated SMTP account rather than the generic mailer on the web server.

The a common confusion and misconception is that you are using SMTP ***OR*** `wp_mail()`. Actually what you're doing is changing what `wp_mail()` is **using** to send.

So you're still using `wp_mail()`.  Properly configured, anything going through `wp_mail()` will be going through your SMTP account.